# Проблема с Quaternion в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю 2d шутер, пистолет поворачивается в зависимости от курсора, если нажимаем лкм, то вылетает создаются пуля,которая принимает аргументы: start.position и pistol.transform.rotation

```
Instantiate(bollet, StartPos.position, pistol.transform.rotation);
```

Решил сделать разброс, путём прибавления к transform.rotation числа четыре, но напрямую к transform.rotation я прибавить ничего не могу.
Решил проблему так:

```
  Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(pistol.transform.rotation.x, pistol.transform.rotation.y, pistol.transform.rotation.z+4);
Instantiate(bollet, StartPos.position, rot);
```

Но в таком случае пуля летит вправо + 4. Когда вывожу pistol.transform.rotation.z, то выводится число, которое не достигает одного и минус одного, то есть
-0.9835,08953 и тд. (Обычно именно в таких значениях). Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать, но ошибку с градусами объяснить могу.

**transform.rotation.x (/y/z)**- возвращает поворот не в градусах, а в границе [-1; 1]

Функция **Quaternion.Euler()** принимает именно значения в градусах. Что бы получить значение поворота в градусах нужно написать **transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x (/y/z)**

Comment: Просто transform.eulerAngles, без rotation. Следовательно ТС нужно заменить скрипт на Quaternion.Euler(pistol.transform.eulerAngles.x, pistol.transform.eulerAngles.y, pistol.transform.eulerAngles.z+4);

Comment: Кстати, да. Не знал что можно не писать rotation